# Provisioning profile includes newer version of signing certificate

Tags: ios, xamarin, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, visual-studio-app-center

We have already published an iOS App in the AppStore. When we try to update the App, We identified that the Signing Certificate and Provisional Profile are expired. One of my team mate recreated a PROD certificate and gave me the .p12 file. I updated the expired Provisional Profile in Apple Developer center with the new Signing certificate and configured the .p12 file in AppCenter with the newly updated Provisional Profile.  But AppCenter throws an exception "Provisioning profile "XXXX" includes newer version of signing certificate "XXXX"

Not Sure how to solve the issue. Any Help is appreciated.

Tried SO search, can't find anything relevant.

Comment: Did your teammate give you the private key? Or is the p12 he gave you the private key?  He can find the private key within his keychains on his mac computer and then export it and send it to you if this is the case.

Comment: Thank You. It looks like i selected wrong key when i updated the Provisional Certificate. Once i fix that, Everything seems to be working. My bad. Sorry. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar error when I was building an iOS app with App Center.

My problem was that when I exported the P12 I didn't export the keys correctly, either didn't include the key or I selected the wrong key. Similar to the photo below:
[image]

In order to fix this issue, you need to do the following:

1. Go to your `Keychain Access`
2. Select `login` keychain
3. Select `My Certificates` tab
4. If you haven't imported your `.cer` certificate into your keychain yet, then you need to import it. You can do that by dragging your `.cer` file into the keychain and entering the password. What I also did is remove the imported certificate and re-imported it.
5. Now that it's imported, you need to export the certificate as P12 format, in order to do that you need to select the `certificate` and it's `key` (important) just like in the image below[image]
6. Last, you need to right click the selected certificates -> click `Export 2 items` -> Select save location -> Enter Password -> That's all.

You should be able to use the P12 certificate and creating builds.